# Is it possible to install multiple programs via script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, npm, cmd, nativescript

I need to re-create the development environment on my machine, and put exact applications on co-workers machine ( not in same office ).

#### What We Need Installed

So basically we need a NativeScript development environment created.

This will include programs like, NativeScript CLI, Android Studio, Node, etc.

#### Ideal Solution

Ideally I would like to write a script that would install the necessary programs without any ( or minimal ) attendance .

Can someone show me how I would create such a script?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install NodeJS silently by downloading the most recent MSI installer and running `msiexec /qn /l* node-log.txt /i node-vX.X.XX-x64.msi`. This will install Node and NPM.

Once you've installed NPM, you can install Nativescript with `npm install -g nativescript`

You can install the Android studio IDE silently with the `/S` switch, and the SDK silently using `/S /Allusers`.
You can set the `Android_Home` environment variable inside `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment`

#### References:

https://gist.github.com/manuelbieh/4178908

https://www.nativescript.org/blog/installing-nativescript-on-windows

http://www.edugeek.net/forums/windows-7/173153-android-studio-unattended-install.html#post1485712

Answer (score 0):

You can use [autoit](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/) to create script, code what and in what order need to be installed. Than you can either put all programs version on one usb with your script - in this way you can also controll version of software installed or call to download and install from internet.
You can also include GUI with the script as well as you can create `.exe` file and end user need just to execute it.

Another option would be to create `.bat` file and code step by step what need to be installed. Look at [batch file command list](http://www.trytoprogram.com/batch-file-commands/) to see what commands are available.

Those are just two options, possibilities are endless, depend on what you feel most comfortable.